# How does Counterspying work with multiple spies?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civilization 6, when you assign spies to counter-spying, you're prompted to choose which district (or city center) to assign them to. The spy then defends that district and any adjacent districts. You can have multiple spies in the same city, each assigned to a different district.

What happens if an enemy spy attempts a mission within range of multiple defending spies? Specifically:

- Do multiple spies provide more defense than one spy?
- Which spy gets credit/experience for catching enemy spies?

Answer (score 5):

> Do multiple spies provide more defense than one spy?

In a way. It's not a matter of the defense (i.e. catch chance) going up, but rather that the enemy spy has to do two dice rolls, one for each spy.

> Which spy gets credit/experience for catching enemy spies?

Whichever spy's roll caught the enemy spy. However, it is unclear to me which spy gets to roll first - it seems plausible that this is based on who was assigned to counterspy first but I have no confirmation on that.

Comment: Interesting. Spies are a bit rare to stack them very often, but it's something to keep in mind for important spaceports.